# Converting Unity .fbx model to .stl using the exporter?

Tags: unity

We bought [this script](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3397) asset from the Unity store. We need to run it to convert some .fbx files to .stl.
Is there any simple guide on how to run a script from the asset store?

Comment: *Well aware this an extreme noob question*